# Resetting Git in VSCode?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, visual-studio-code

I have a node git project open in VSCode and I did not add a `.gitignore` initially so all the `node_modules` files got staged on `npm i`.

I then added a `.gitignore` with `node_modules/` in it, but the files are not being ignored.  I then `rm -fr node_modules .vscode` and I do not have a `.git` folder in the project, yet the files are still showing as staged and if I click on them they open, so VSCode is holding on to them somehow.  This is the result of `ls -la` on the project:

```
    total 36
    drwxr-xr-x  3 ole ole 4096 Mar 25 12:23 .
    drwxr-xr-x 22 ole ole 4096 Mar 23 23:55 ..
    -rw-r--r--  1 ole ole   13 Mar 25 12:26 .gitignore
    -rw-r--r--  1 ole ole  280 Mar 22 16:50 jest.config.js
    -rw-r--r--  1 ole ole  303 Mar 24 21:53 package.json
    -rw-r--r--  1 ole ole  379 Mar 24 21:53 package-lock.json
    drwxr-xr-x  4 ole ole 4096 Mar 24 22:42 src
    -rw-r--r--  1 ole ole 5561 Mar 22 18:33 tsconfig.json
```

Thoughts on how to reset the project so that it only shows the non `node_modules` files?[image]

### Update

Instead of using VSCode to perform the first commit I used the commandline, and it shows the correct results.  However VSCode still shows a bunch of files from other parts of the file system that are not part of the project even after the first commit.

Also if I switch to a different project `cd ../differentproject` and run `code .` it still shows the same uncommited files for that project ...

Comment: The `.gitignore` file does not  "untrack" files that are already tracked by git. You need to manually remove them from git.

Comment: git has a command for removing files from it, it accepts wildcards so you can do (not sure of correct syntax) git remove node_modules/*

Comment: Also, you say that you do not have a `.git` folder in the project. This is suspect. You probably have one but VSCode does not show it. Also, your file explorer might also hide it by default because its name begins with a dot. On Nautilus (the default file explorer on Ubuntu), use `Ctrl+H` to show/hide hidden files.

Comment: Fun fact : hiding files that begin with a dot [was originally a bug then became a convention](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88875/why-are-filenames-that-start-with-a-dot-hidden-can-i-hide-files-without-using-a). "It's not a bug, it's a feature."

Comment: There really is no `.git` folder.  I pasted the result of `ls -la` in the question.

Comment: I just had a similar issue. I think it's just vscode that is stuck rendering all the node_modules as change and the git part of it is completely locked up. Just restart it.